# Xcode 4 with native GIT support / How to (local with terminal usage most of the time)

Tags: git, xcode4

sorry, but I need a little help with Xcode 4 and git. I just switched to Xcode 4 BECAUSE it supports git, but by now I don't know how to set it up right.

I would like to use the terminal most of the time, as the UI of Xcode is to slow to use instead of a quick

```
$ git co master
```

or so, but I would like to use the pretty handy diff and maybe also commit function Xcode comes with. 
If I let Xcode set up the local repo, I can't find it with terminal, if I set the repo with the terminal, I can't figure out how to tell Xcode "there is a repo, please have a look and get a notice of all the branches". Instead it creates it's own local copy so I have two visible, accessible but independent project folders.

I googled, but I can't find a good tutorial for a local repo (later on I'll try to add a remote repo too^^). Is there any understandable documentation of how to do set up git with Xcode 4 that will work nicely with any changes/commits/tags I'll do within the terminal?

I know that I'll get the "the file disappeared" message when swithcing branches, but I'll also get that if I switch through the Xcode UI, so I gotta deal with that (side-question: I never had to, but how can I join all those people asking Apple to implement that the files that do not exist in the new branch just silently close, instead of annoying me with popups?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I managed to get this done, although I find it quite confusing to get there, this is the way I set up projects (from now on), to use git from the terminal most of the time, but having the option for the Xcode-Diff and commit:

Create your folder.
Create a Subfolder
(everything in the subfolder will be subversioned, everything in the some level as this subfolder, aka inside the folder won't.. I always need that)
create your .gitignore (the content of gitignore will be listed at the end)
add another file, eg. a ReadMe.rtf
in terminal, set up your git like usuall with:

```
$ cd <path to your subfolder>
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m "Your commit message"
```

switch to Xcode, create a new Project like file->new->project (you should not be able to set up a git repo through this dialog any longer, the check box should be disabled)
Check back inside the organizer, there should be a repo called like your Subfolder.

To add a remote repo, just do as usual in Terminal.

The .gitignore content:

```
.svn/entries
build

.DS_Store
*.swp
*~.nib

build/

*.pbxuser
*.perspective
*.perspectivev3

//for xcode 4
xcuserdata

//User-specific project settings
*.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
```

Hope that helps someone else too :)