# Using both Xcode and Terminal for git commands

Tags: xcode, git

I am new to using git and I followed some instructions for using it directly form the terminal. I noticed when I opened the project that Xcode also showed this repository clearly, even though it was an existing project and Xcode did not itself create the repository (I didn't have that option checked when the project was created).

I read on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370314/xcode-4-with-native-git-support-how-to-local-with-terminal-usage-most-of-the) that Xcode keeps its repositories separate from the repository created using git manually from terminal. Yet, my experience suggests Xcode is in fact finding it fine.

My questions are simply:

1. Does it matter from the sake of functionality whether the repository is created with Xcode or manually from the terminal?
2. Can the two be used interchangeably on the same project? Will the same repository be used?
3. Is perhaps the latest Xcode 4.6 and improvement in this area and this is why the above-linked question suggested problems that I am not encountering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I read on this question that Xcode keeps its repositories separate from the repository created using git manually from terminal. Yet, my experience suggests Xcode is in fact finding it fine.

You are right, it is fine (at least for what I use it for).

> Does it matter from the sake of functionality whether the repository is created with Xcode or manually from the terminal?

No, it doesn't.

> Can the two be used interchangeably on the same project? Will the same repository be used?

Yes and yes.

> Is perhaps the latest Xcode 4.6 and improvement in this area and this is why the above-linked question suggested problems that I am not encountering?

Likely, although at least with Xcode 4.5 it worked for me as well.